# Is there a difference between selecting from a view or from a table?

Tags: sql, optimization, view

I have some C# code which is trying to pull in 1000+ different entries through an SQL query (think, select col1 from table1 where id = x)
at each iteration of the loop x changes to present a new entry.

Is there a difference between running this query on a view or on a table?

or is there any other way to optimize this procedure?

Comment: The very general answer is that you want to reduce chatting with the server (and moving data around) as much as possible. So, if you can pull in all the data you need in ONE trip to the server and then work with that data in code, it will be faster. As to your question about Table vs View.... well that very much depends on a large number of factors too.

Answer (score 0):

A table contains data, a view is just a `SELECT` statement which has been saved in the database (more or less, depending on your database).

The advantage of a view is that it can join data from several tables thus creating a new view of it. Say you have a database with salaries and you need to do some complex statistical queries on it.

Instead of sending the complex query to the database all the time, you can save the query as a view and then `SELECT * FROM view`